# Sum of Some Binomial Terms Equals Zero

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Let $q$ and $\ell$ be positive integers. Then the sum
>   $$
> \sum_{k=q}^\ell (-1)^{k+q}\binom{k}{q}\binom{\ell}{k} = 
> \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 \mbox{ if } \ell =q\\ 0 \mbox{ if }\ell >q\end{array}\right.
> $$

I don't see what to do here. Can we interpret it combinatorially somehow?

Comment: What is the source of the claim. Is it from some book? It is from an assignment? In general, it is good to [provide some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for a question asked here.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I apologize if my post seems inappropriate. I usually provide the sources of my questions. This particular sum arose while I was trying to solve a problem. I was able to see that the statement of the problem holds if and only if this was true. So I posted it here. I really didn't see what I could have written about the source which would be fruitful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Considering how many questions are being closed for lack of context, I simply had to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Assume that $\ell>q$, since the other case is trivial. Suppose that we have white slips of paper numbered $1$ through $\ell$. If $k\le q\le\ell$, $\binom{\ell}k\binom{k}q$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ of those slips and color them blue, then choose $q$ of the $k$ blue slips and circle the number. This is clearly the same as choosing $q$ of the original $\ell$ slips, coloring them blue, *and* circling the number, and then choosing $k-q$ of the remaining $\ell-q$ white slips and coloring them blue, so $\binom{\ell}k\binom{k}q=\binom{\ell}q\binom{\ell-q}{k-q}$. And $k+q\equiv k-q\pmod2$, so, setting $j=k-q$,

$$\sum_{k=q}^\ell(-1)^{k+q}\binom{\ell}k\binom{k}q=\binom{\ell}q\sum_{j=0}^{\ell-q}(-1)^j\binom{\ell-q}j\;.$$

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Yes. The RHS of the last equation is clearly 0. Thank you so  mcuh. this increases my ability to interpret binomial series combinatorially.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: You're very welcome.